# reading integer values from json return dictionary in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am receiving a JSON response as

> `apiResponse =
>
>        {
>           Appointment = 4;
>
>           Goals = 0;
>
>           Holiday = 0;
>
>           LessonPlan = 0;
>
>           ServiceLevel = 0;
>
>           SiteSetup = 0;
>
>           Student = 2;
>
>           TherapyLog = 0;
>
>           Worksite = 0;
>
>       };`

i used to get value as
`NSMutableDictionary* resultTables=[result objectForKey:@"apiResponse"];`

```
int countVals=[[result objectForKey:tablename] intValue] ;
```

when i am checking

```
if (countVals>=0) 
{
   NSLog(@"Tables Names:%@",tablename);
  [updatedTables addObject:tablename];

}else
{
   NSLog(@"Tables Names:%@",tablename);
   NSLog(@"no data to update");

}
```

table name is not adding to updateTables ARRAY.
What is my Wrong...

Comment: Have you initialized updatedTables?

Comment: I got solution.I used wrong dictionary

Comment: What's table name here?

Comment: You should delete this question then.

Comment: Yes,i done.I for getting value i used main return json dictionary.Its wrong.I have to use updatedTables......

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is entirely specific to the asker's situation and it is unlikely that anyone else will make this same mistake in their code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int countVals=[[resultTables objectForKey:tablename] intValue] ;
```

You should use `resultTables` to get table name.